# How to set limit range

Tags: python, matplotlib, yaxis, x-axis

Why doesn't matplotlib.pyplot.xlim() method work in the below example?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
l = [0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0]
plt.plot(l,l)
plt.xlim = (-10,10)
plt.show()
```

[image: chart]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`matplotlib.pyplot.xlim`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xlim), [`matplotlib.pyplot.ylim`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ylim) are functions. You should call them instead of assigning to them:

```
plt.ylim(-10,10)
plt.xlim(-10,10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`plt.xlim` is a function. Instead of changing this function, you need to use it by calling it with the respective limits.

```
plt.xlim((-10,10))
```